Get response from RS485 modbus using PHP
I'm trying to get a response from a command I'm sending using PHP to an RS485 device using the script below:
<?php
class rapidserial{
  function _blocking($device,$mode){
      stream_set_blocking($device, $mode);
      return true;
     }
  }
$rapidserial = new rapidserial();
$device = "COM3";
shell_exec("mode $device BAUD=9600 PARITY=n DATA=8 STOP=2 xon=off octs=off rts=off"); 
$comport = fopen($device, "r+b");
if ($comport === false)
    {
    die("Failed opening com port<br/>");
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Com Port Open<br/>"; 
    }
//Set non-blocking mode for writing
$rapidserial->_blocking($comport,0);
$atcmd = "\x0A\x04\x00\x00\x00\x49\x30\x87"; //
fputs($comport, $atcmd);
usleep(2000);
// Set blocking mode for reading
$rapidserial->_blocking($comport,1);
echo 'Response:';
$res = fgets($comport, 4017);
var_dump ($res);
fclose($comport);
?>

This was taken from a related post I made here : https://superuser.com/questions/1815811/issue-addressing-modbus-via-rs485-and-php-on-windows where I was helped to send a command, the script provided by the person that helped me works. Now I'm trying to send a command and get a response back but it's not working, the response is empty.
I have also tried using https://github.com/toggio/PhpSerialModbus but it tells me that it's "'Unable to open the device".
I know I can communicate with the device because if I use some modbus software I can send the command and get the response back.

UPDATE : So I have moved from a Windows device to a Linux device to do this and I have now had some success using a different modbus class in PHP (https://github.com/toggio/PhpSerialModbus) but the issue is that I'm not receiving all of the data back, it seems truncated and even if I try to ask for a register further on (not starting at zero) I do not get all of the data back I'm expecting. I know it is there because if I use the modbus software as shown in the image I can see it.
My code now looks like this :
<?php
include("/var/www/html/PhpSerialModbus.php");
$modbus = new PhpSerialModbus();
$modbus->deviceInit('/dev/ttyUSB0',9600,'none',8,2,'none');
$modbus->deviceOpen();
$modbus->debug = false;
$rawquery="\x0A\x04\x00\x00\x00\x49\x30\x87";
$modbus->sendRawQuery($rawquery.$modbus->crc16($rawquery),false);
$result=$modbus->getResponse(true);
function hex2float($strHex) {
    $hex = sscanf($strHex, "%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x");
    $bin = implode('', array_map('chr', $hex));
    $array = unpack("Gnum", $bin);
    return $array['num'];
}
$bin_result = bin2hex($result);
$bin_result = chunk_split($bin_result, 2, ',');
$bin_result = substr($bin_result, 9);
$myresults = print_r($bin_result, true);
$final_array = explode(",", $myresults);
print_r ($final_array);
?>

Which gives me this:
[0] => 42
[1] => 48
[2] => 33
[3] => 33
[4] => 43
[5] => d3
[6] => 92
[7] => 00
[8] => 43
[9] => 75
[10] => 54
[11] => 86
[12] => 40
[13] => 66
[14] => 66
[15] => 72
[16] => be
[17] => dc
[18] => 7a
[19] => de
[20] => 44
[21] => 5c
[22] => f0
[23] => 0a
[24] => 44
[25] => 34
[26] => 50
[27] => 09
[28] => 42
[29] => f2
[30] => cc
[31] => cd
[32] => be
[33] => f9
[34] => db
[35] => 24
[36] => 40
[37] => 25
[38] => c2
[39] => 8f
[40] => 42
[41] => 06
[42] => cc
[43] => cd
[44] => 42
[45] => 90
[46] => 00
[47] => 07
[48] => 42
[49] => ef
[50] => 99
[51] => 9a
[52] => 43
[53] => d3
[54] => 51
[55] => 65
[56] => 43
[57] => 73
[58] => c2
[59] => 9b
[60] => 40
[61] => 80
[62] =>


On the screenshot, RTS seems disabled but your mode command enables it.

@Olivier thanks, I must have left it on testing, apologies. I've sets it to off with no change to the outcome. I've updated the question accordingly. Thanks for helping.

Did you try with fread() instead of fgets()?

The response on the screenshot starts with 0A, so you should definitely use fread(), because fgets() will interpret that byte as a newline and stop.

@Olivier thanks for your suggestions. I have tried with fread but it times out, as if nothing is being read.

Do you know if the device receives the command?

@Olivier I'm afraid I do not know. The connection is from USB (assigned COM3) to a modbus RS485 device down to the unit in question. I know that the PC, modbus device and cabling is fine as the other modbus software can read/write to it, but I cannot verify if the PHP script is sending the command. I have used the same script to write to another device and it works.

This question is now in two spots. I understand that one was migrated from SU, but I think they should still be consolidated. To the OP, please do this or someone might choose which one on your behalf.

@ChrisHaas Yes, I had posted there by mistake, it has now been migrated.

$rawquery already includes the CRC, so you shouldn't append a second CRC to it.

@Olivier thank you for your reply.  I have tried without it, same result.

Try calling sleep(1); followed by another call to getResponse().

If you are not able to recieve the response then it is due to the machine setting check the machine manual for this, also make the baud rate corrections

@Olivier thank you, this actually does work (in part). When I say in part, it does respond with more data in the second getResponse. I can now see all the data in either the first or second getResponse. My issue now is that the first getResponse length varies which means that the data that I need from the second call is in a different variable each time. It's as if the data is still being truncated in a way and leading to erratic responses (in length). Any idea what might be causing this? Thanks again.

@Olivier It's just dawned on me that I just need to add the two results together and THEN process them and it doesn't matter which part they are in as they will ALL be in the one string/array. I think I've got it!

The reading loop performed by PhpSerialModbus.php is:
while( ($byte = $this->serial->ReadPort()) && ((microtime(true)-$startTime)<3.0)) {
    $responseString=$responseString.$byte;
    usleep(50);
}

There's something wrong with it: it waits 50 microseconds only, which is way too short. No additional data has
enough time to arrive and the loop terminates prematurely. Maybe the developer meant 50 milliseconds instead,
so you could change it like this:
    usleep(50000);

In case you don't want to alter PhpSerialModbus.php, you can do someting like this in your code:
$result = $modbus->getResponse(true);
do
{
    usleep(50000);
    $data = $modbus->getResponse(true);
    $result .= $data;
}
while($data);


Thanks for your help on this one, much appreciated, all is working correctly now.
